# Error while debugging using gdb debugger on VS Code using Windows 10 and MINGW complier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I was following the documentation on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw to set up my C++ development environment on VS code.

I succesfully created my build task and ran my build task, but when i tried to set up my debugger (GDB debugger), i got the following output on the terminal.

```
C:\Users\Ayon\c++\helloworld> cmd /C "c:\Users\Ayon\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.28.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-shlwrnf5.x12 --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-vg12hskh.c52 --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-nrcvh0zz.0u0 --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-m1nmxyvs.qk2 --dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Im curious as to how the "cmd /" came about in the output. Please help me fix this error.

Thanks in advance.

For reference, here is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add mingw64/bin to your system path? Here's how to do so:

```
Control panel -> Edit path -> Environment variables -> Path -> New
```

You can also find more guidance on 
[vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) official website.

Comment: Yes I did. The problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the MinGW installation. I also faced this problem for a long time, solved it by doing the following:

1. Completely removing the current MinGW [Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/pLifr8EEHYU)
2. Installing MinGW-w64 from the [site](http://mingw-w64.org/) mentioned in vscode documentation. [installation video tutorial](https://youtu.be/0HD0pqVtsmw)

After this, I followed the configuration mentioned in this [video](https://youtu.be/r1zCtg_wqCA). The video is for c code, but you can make the required changes to c++ code. Now I'm able to debug in vscode.

By this way, you will also be able to use the latest versions of gdb and g++ available.